# How to remove rejected apps from Google Play Developer Console?

Tags: android, google-play

Can some one say me how to remove rejected apps from Google Play Developer Console ??

Actually my app was rejected once and I am no longer interested in publishing it, So please help me.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cant remove apk entirely. However you can unpublish instead. It will remove link from google play store and no further user will be able to search or install.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove the app once you have published it on Google Play Developer Console